# Copy remotely several directories in SVN by one command

Tags: svn

I have next directories in SVN repository:

myrepo/trunk/rootDir/dir1

myrepo/trunk/rootDir/dir2

myrepo/trunk/rootDir/dir3

myrepo/trunk/rootDir/fld1

myrepo/trunk/rootDir/fld2

...

Is it possible to move all these repositories from rootDir to myrepo/trunk/rootDir2 by one remote command?

I do not want to use command like next for each directory:

svn -m "Move dir1" rename http://hostname:8080/svn/myrepo/trunk/rootDir/dir1
 http://hostname:8080/svn/myrepo/trunk/rootDir2

svn -m "Move dir1" rename http://hostname:8080/svn/myrepo/trunk/rootDir/dir2
 http://hostname:8080/svn/myrepo/trunk/rootDir2
...

And I do not want to move these directories using working copy.
I would like to move these directories directly in repository.

Answer (score 1):

The only way to do this in one commit/revision is to use the working copy.